# Error "double** to double*" while passing pointer in a function c/c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function that takes a `double *result`. I am aware that pointers need to be passed by reference in a function. When I call the function `void ComputeSeriesPointer(double x, int n, double *result);` in main with `ComputeSeriesPointer(x, n, &result);`, I get the error:

```
cannot convert ‘double**’ to ‘double*’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘void ComputeSeriesPointer(double, int, double*)’                            
 ComputeSeriesPointer(x, n, &result);                                                                                                                                                  
                                   ^
```

When working with pointers, aren't they all passed using the `&` key? The in class examples were all done this way. Even on the internet things were done this way. Any explanation/clarification would be great.

I am also running this with a c++ compiler (as instructed by my professor) because I am using the `pow` function.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Don't compile C code with a C++ compiler and vice versa. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. Also, use the features of the language you use.

Comment: "I am aware that pointers need to be passed by reference in a function" - A pointer is not a reference. Use a reference type if you need a reference.

Comment: I appreciate the tip. I'm a first year programmer, so I welcome criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you are doing without seeing the complete code, but If you are doing something like this:

```
void ComputeSeriesPointer(double, int, double*){
    // ...
}

int main(){
    double *x = ...;
    ComputeSeriesPointer(1.0, 1, &x); 
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Then, the problem is the `&x`. The `&` operator is used to extract a variable address. In this case, your variable is already a pointer, so writing `&x` you are getting a "pointer to pointer", in other words, a `double**`. That's your problem. Call your function in this way: `ComputeSeriesPointer(1.0, 1, x)`

Comment: A simple rule is if you pass an object to a function argument with the same type, you don't need a specific operator. Things are _slightly_ different for true reference types.

Answer (score 0):

The function is expecting you to pass the memory address of an actual `double` variable, not the memory address of a `double*` pointer variable:

```
double result; // NOT double*!
ComputeSeriesPointer(x, n, &result);
```

You can also do this:

```
double result; // NOT double*!
double *presult = &result;
ComputeSeriesPointer(x, n, presult);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message implies that the type of `result` is already `double *`. You don't need to use the `&` operator if the variable is already a pointer of the appropriate type. So you should do

```
ComputeSeriesPointer(x, n, result);
```

Either that, or you need to change the declaration of the `result` variable in the caller from `double *` to `double`.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are doing this:

```
double *myNewResult;
...
ComputeSeriesPointer(x, n, &myNewResult);
```

By doing this you are passing the address of a `double*` not `double`. You dont need `double *myNewResult`, just `double myNewResult`. Or if you need `myNewResult` to be a `double*` you can just pass it to the function like this:

```
ComputeSeriesPointer(x, n, myNewResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is declared like

```
void ComputeSeriesPointer(double, int, double*);
```

its third parameter has type `double *`

But you call the function like

```
ComputeSeriesPointer(x, n, &result);
```

where the third argument has type `double **`

You need to call the function like

```
ComputeSeriesPointer(x, n, result);
```

Or change the function declaration and correspondingly its definition such a way that the third parametr had type `double **`

```
void ComputeSeriesPointer(double, int, double **);
```

Answer (score -1):

Passing a pointer into a function *is* passing by reference; the pointer is the "reference." (C++ muddied waters a little bit by also introducing a "reference" type which pretends it is not a pointer, but that's not relevant to the code example you've given.)

The & operator means "address of." It takes a thing and returns a pointer to that thing. So,

```
double x = 1; // this is a double
double *pointer_to_x = &x;
double **pointer_to_pointer_to_x = &pointer_to_x;
```

and so on.

We need to see a little bit more of your code calling ComputeSeriesPointer() to answer properly, but my guess is that you have:

```
double *result; // this kind of variable stores *the address of* a double-precision number. 
ComputeSeriesPointer( x, n, &result );
```

but you really want:

```
double result; // this kind of variable stores a double-precision number.
ComputeSeriesPointer( x, n, &result );
```

so that you are passing in the address that you want ComputeSeriesPointer() to write a result into.

Comment: Yes, I have `double *result` as the variable declaration. So, if I kept it as so, I would pass it in as `ComputeSeriesPointer( x, n, result );`?

Comment: @NickPredey Yes -- but what does `double *result` point at before you pass it into ComputeSeriesPointer()?

Comment: I just realized it doesn't. After reading your answer, I realized that passing by reference means the function will be declared as `double ComputeSeriesPointer(double, int, double*)`. Something I realized, as it was the first time I've seen it written. Thank you for answering.

Comment: C is strictly pass by value only. If you pass a pointer to a function, you actively take the address of an object with an operator or an implicit conversion (like for arrays). But that is passed **by value** to the function. There is a clear distinction between passing by reference and by pointer: A pointer is an object itself. It has a value which is independent from the value of the object it points to. And you have to use an explicit operator to access the object. A reference is (briefly) an alternative way to access an object, but it has no user-accessible value by itself.